# Creating acronyms in Python

Tags: python

In Python, how do I make an acronym of a given string?

Like, input string:

```
'First Second Third'
```

Output:

```
'FST'
```

I am trying something like:

```
>>> for e in x:
        print e[0]
```

But it is not working... Any suggestions on how this can be done? I am sure there is a proper way of doing this but I can't seem to figure it out. Do I have to use `re`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
print "".join(e[0] for e in x.split())
```

Your loop actually loops over all characters in the string `x`.  If you would like to loop over the words, you can use `x.split()`.

Comment: the 'split' here being the relevant bit that was missing in the original.

Comment: Just a difference of two seconds, so +1 for you!

Comment: Thanks, I did think of using this but somehow I was sticking to my own solution.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to use capitals only

```
>>>line = ' What AboutMe '
>>>filter(str.isupper, line)
'WAM'
```

What about words that may not be Leading Caps.

```
>>>line = ' What is Up '
>>>''.join(w[0].upper() for w in line.split())
'WIU'
```

What about only the Caps words.

```
>>>line = ' GNU is Not Unix '
>>>''.join(w[0] for w in line.split() if w[0].isupper())
'GNU'
```

Comment: ''.join(w[0].upper() for w in line.split()) should be ''.join(w[0] for w in line.split()).upper()

Answer (score 6):

Without `re`:

```
>>> names = 'Vincent Vega Jules Winnfield'
>>> ''.join(x[0] for x in names.split())
'VVJW'
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do things the way that is grammatically correct (regardless of locale), use `title()`, then `filter()`:

```
acronym = filter(str.isupper, my_string.title())
```

`title()` is pretty awesome; it makes a string titlecased and is correct according to locale.

Answer (score 3):

Now for something a little bit different...

```
words = "There ain't no such thing as a free lunch."
acronym = ''.join(word[0] for word in words.upper().split())
print acronym
# TANSTAAFL
```

([TANSTAAFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moon_is_a_Harsh_Mistress#Book_3%3a_TANSTAAFL.21) is a fairly well-know one, BTW).

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 'First Second Third'
x = s.split(' ')
for e in x:
    print e[0]
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Also you could use

`re.split('\W')`

to split the line/text on non-word characters.  This might be a little bit more robust.

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion so we can remove words like to, and , of as well as signs like',':

```
stopwords = ['to', 'a', 'for', 'by', 'an', 'am', 'the', 'so', 'it', 'and', "The"]
Phrase=input("please enter the phrase you need its acronym: ")
acro=""
for i in range(len(stopwords)):
    Phrase=Phrase.replace(stopwords[i]+' ',"")
    Phrase=Phrase.replace(',',' ')
Phrase=Phrase.upper()
Words=Phrase.split( )
for word in Words:
    acro = acro + word[0]
print(acro)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do acronym with regular expression, leaving numbers as is:

```
import re
words = "internet explorer 10"
print re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z])[a-z,A-Z]+\s*",r"\1",words).upper()
```

**IE10**

Answer (score 0):

There is a python-based tool for this task, that suggests multiple acronyms, that can be installed via

```
pip install acronym
```

Source code repo is here: https://github.com/bacook17/acronym

Answer (score -1):

this is my suggestion

```py
abbr=input("enter:")
list1=abbr.split()
print(list1)

for x in range(0,len(list1)):
    print(list1[x][:1],end="")
```